# Using powershell to disable services, fails with 'specified service does not exist'

Tags: powershell, service, windows-8.1

I am trying to run the following powershell command to disable Superfetch on a Windows 8.1 machine. Powershell window is open as Administrator and I am logged in as administrator.

```
Set-Service -name Superfetch -StartupType Disabled -Status Stopped
```

However I receive the following error

```
Service 'Superfetch (SysMain)' cannot be configured due to the following error: The specified service does not exist as an installed service
+ CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Set-Service], ServiceCommandException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotSetService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetServiceCommand
+ PSComputerName        : xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Clearly this service is installed, I see it in the installed services snap-in. I see the CategoryInfo as 'PermissionDenied'. How can I disable this service via powershell? I am logged in as an admin!
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct service name?  Open up a command prompt and type sc query.  You might have to dump it to a text file.  This will give you the correct service name you're looking for.  It's entirely possible that the service name is called something other than the display name.

Comment: yes. If I run 'Get-Service' with that name it returns the service object. not to mention the fact that it keys with its authoritative name (SysMain) leads me to believe the service is correct.

Comment: See @Bartłomiej Zarzecki's answer below.

Comment: One extra thing for me. When I wanted to disable a SQL Server (named instance), its canonical name was `MSSQL$INSTANCE`, I needed to remember to escape the $ because of powershell. The $ character is escaped by prepending a backtick: `$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because the service name is "**SysMain**" not "**Superfetch**".

> PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-Service -name **SysMain** -StartupType
>   Disabled -Status Stopped

However You will probably get now this:

> Set-Service : Cannot stop service 'Superfetch (SysMain)' because it is
>   dependent on other services.

because of these dependencies:
[image: superfetch service dependencies]

Comment: ok, you guys were right. friendly name is not enough for -set-service, you gotta use canonical name, which is available by running 'Get-Service'

Comment: @Richthofen however You can use "Get-Service superfetch | Set-Service -StartupType Disabled -Status Stopped"